# Getting java.sql.SQLException: Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed

Tags: java, sql

my code works fine but I am getting this exception a lot and it's causing a little lag ... I suspect this part to produce the exception

```
try {
        try {
            rs = dbConnection.getStatement().executeQuery("SELECT * FROM healthgym.member WHERE member_id = " + id);
            rs.next();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Controller.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        m.setMember_id(rs.getInt("member_id"));
        m.setRec_id(rs.getInt("rec_id"));
        m.setTrainer_id(rs.getInt("trainer_id"));
        m.setFname(rs.getString("fname"));
        m.setLname(rs.getString("lname"));
        m.setMname(rs.getString("mname"));
        m.setEmail(rs.getString("email"));
        m.setPhoneNo(rs.getInt("phoneno"));
        m.setAge(rs.getInt("age"));............
```

I use the m object later to fill some text fields

Edit 1 : I am still getting that exception ... here is what happens exactly ... I select a row in Jtable and I press the edit button the exception is thrown **but it works fine**
here is what's called when i press the edit button

```
  private void editButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    int id = ((Number) model.getValueAt(jTable1.getSelectedRow(), 0)).intValue() ;
    System.out.println(id);

      m = new Member();
    c.getMember(m,id);

    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new EditMember(c,model,m).setVisible(true);
        }
    });


}
```

And EditMember is a GUI here is its constructor..

```
public class EditMember extends javax.swing.JFrame {

/** Creates new form EditMember */
public EditMember(Controller c, ResultSetTableModel model , Member m) {

    initComponents();
    this.c = c;
    this.model = model ;
    this.m = m ;
    memberID.setText(Integer.toString(m.getMember_id()));
    recID.setText(Integer.toString(m.getRec_id()));
    trainerID.setText(Integer.toString(m.getTrainer_id()));
    fName.setText(m.getFname());
    lName.setText(m.getLname());.......
```

Edit 2 :

That;s where the exception happens :

```
public Object getValueAt( int row, int column )
  throws IllegalStateException


  {
      // ensure database connection is available
      if ( !dbConnection.isConnectedToDatabase() )
         throw new IllegalStateException( "Not Connected to Database" );
  // obtain a value at specified ResultSet row and column

  try
  {
     resultSet.absolute( row + 1 );
     return resultSet.getObject( column + 1 );
  } // end try
  catch ( SQLException sqlException )
  {
      System.out.println("Exception from here dude");
     sqlException.printStackTrace();
  } // end catch
```

I guess the problem is because I am using the same resultset that I used before to construct the JTable.

Comment: Where are you getting the exception? Where is the ResultSet being closed? Where is `rs` declared? Is it shared between threads (bad idea)?

Comment: I specified where ... rs is declared in the class which has the getMember method. No, It;s not shared .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it should be

```
    if(rs.next(){
  m.setMember_id(rs.getInt("member_id"));
}
```

So all set value will be in try block.

Why you are getting error ?
Because sometime when result is empty the result set will be closed by rs.next()

If you put it in while {where there are multiple row in result of query} or if {when you accept only one row in query output }.

Comment: I am still getting the exception

Comment: will you like to share full code ?
where you are closing rs ?

Comment: sorry with this piece of code. I have no idea about your problem.

Comment: I have located the real location of the error ... I will edit my post .

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
    Statement stmt = dbConnection.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery
    ("SELECT * FROM healthgym.member WHERE member_id = " + id);

    // Fetch each row from the result set
    while (rs.next()) {
        // Get the data from the row using the column index
        m.setMember_id(rs.getInt("member_id"));
        m.setRec_id(rs.getInt("rec_id"));
        m.setTrainer_id(rs.getInt("trainer_id"));
        m.setFname(rs.getString("fname"));
        m.setLname(rs.getString("lname"));
        m.setMname(rs.getString("mname"));
        m.setEmail(rs.getString("email"));
        m.setPhoneNo(rs.getInt("phoneno"));
        m.setAge(rs.getInt("age"));
    }
} catch (SQLException e) {
}
```

Try this way.